# Why does my filtered Object.values() return weird data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I wrote a Vue3 component that is supposed to display data in chips. I pass it an Object which key is an index and one of the fields of the values is the element to display.

The whole documented code is below

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div>a fixed entry during debug</div>
    <q-chip v-for="alert in failedAlerts" :key="alert.Id" color="orange">{{ alert.FullTargetName }}</q-chip>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

import {toRef, Ref, computed, watch} from 'vue'
import log from 'assets/log'

interface Alert {
  IsOK: boolean;
  FullTargetName: string,
  Why: string,
  Extra: string,
  Id: string,
  When: string
}

function alertFactory(): Alert {
  return {
    Extra: '', FullTargetName: 'dummy alert', Id: '0', IsOK: false, When: '0', Why: 'dummy alert explanation',
  }
}

export default {
  name: 'Homemonitor',
  // the complete props definitiin is temporarily commented out to make sure the problem
  // does not come from here
  // props: {
  //   alerts: {
  //     type: Object,
  //     default: () => alertFactory(),
  //   },
  // },
  props: ['alerts'],
  setup(props) {
    // TODO: review the global eslint exclusions below
    /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call */
    /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return */
    /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access */

    let failedAlerts = computed(() => Object.values(toRef(props, 'alerts')).filter((x: Alert) => !x.IsOK))

    return {failedAlerts}
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

When looking in DevTools → Vue, I see that `failedAlerts`, instead of being a neat Array of `Alert`, is

[image]

`alert` in both `props and` setup → failedAlerts → alerts` has the expected content

[image]

`Object.values()` returns the values of the object, as an Array (which I then filer). **I expected that `failedAlerts` would be an Array made up of the values of `alerts` (filtered).**

Using the data above, that would be *almost* that: (`IsOK` is `true` so it would have been filtered out, but the idea is that)

```
// failedAlerts

[
  {
    "IsOK":true,
    "FullTargetName":"bind → Amazon_Fire",
    "Why":"",
    "Extra":"",
    "Id":"8bd3b2c7fe73ea6c0d0aac324baaa354",
    "When":"2021-08-19T13:02:33+02:00"
  },
(...)
]
```

Why is `failedAlerts` what it is in my case?

---

EDIT: after a hard stare on the types mess I had in my code (and mostly thanks to @EstusFlask perseverence) I think I came up with the correct code for the `<script>` part.

```js
<script lang="ts">

import {computed, Ref, toRef, watch} from 'vue'

interface Alert {
  IsOK: boolean;
  FullTargetName: string,
  Why: string,
  Extra: string,
  Id: string,
  When: string
}

function alertFactory(): Record<string, Alert> {
  return {
    'dummy index':
        {
          Extra: '', FullTargetName: 'dummy alert', Id: '0', IsOK: false, When: '0', Why: 'dummy alert explanation',
        },
  }
}

export default {
  name: 'Homemonitor',
  props: {
    alerts: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
      // default: () => alertFactory(),
    },
  },
  // props: ['alerts'],
  setup(props) {
    // TODO: review the global eslint exclusions below
    /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call */
    /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return */
    /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access */

    let failedAlerts = computed(() => Object.values(props.alerts as Ref<Record<string, Alert>>).filter((x: Alert) => !x.IsOK))

    return {failedAlerts}
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: It returns what it should, i.e. an array of object values. Please, clarify what exactly you expect failedAlerts to look like.

Comment: @EstusFlask: sorry for the lack of clarity. I added an explicit sentence and an example output with what I expected

Comment: You cheated TS by asserting that props.alerts is an array, `Ref<Alert[]>`, but it's an object. And this `alertFactory()` is an object, not an array either.

Comment: @EstusFlask: ah crap, too much copy/paste. Thanks! I removed the assertion but the problem is the same.

Comment: try this- `let failedAlerts = computed(() => Object.values(toRef(props, 'alerts').value).filter((x: Alert) => !x.IsOK))`

Comment: @ShivamSingla: ah yes! of course - `.value`. I am still not used to that with Vue3. Could you please turn your comment into an answer, i would gladly accept it.

Comment: @WoJ FYI, `toRef(props, 'alerts')` is unnecessary. You could've just used `props.alerts` in the computed, and not have to unwrap any refs.

Comment: @tony19: ah. I used the 2nd paragraph of https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#toref as a guide (but I am starting wth Vue3 after quite some time with Vue2 so I am still in the dark)

Comment: toRef is needed where you need to have a ref to pass somewhere, but here you don't. If props.alerts were an array, it would be just `computed(() => props.alerts.filter...)`. Here it's not, so consider making a decision on what `alerts` should look like and fixing it. It shouldn't be an object if you expect an array, and vice versa

Comment: @EstusFlask `alerts` is an object (I restored the initial `props`, commented out in the question) and it was always intended to be an Object (the error you found initially is a stupid copy/paste mistake). I now understand why `toRef` is not needed (I do not pass the props anywhere) - thanks a lot for that!

Comment: If it's an object (singular) then by naming it `alerts` (plural) you making a wrong assumption that it's a collection, while it's a single entity. It cannot conform `Alert[]` type because it's `Alert`.. And it's unclear what's supposed to be filtered out in `failedAlerts` (plural)` and why it's supposed to be a collection. This way can be either empty array or an array with length 1, correct? I believe the problem lies outside Vue 3 API and the way Object.values behaves.

Comment: Currently the question is contradictory. It would make more sense to me if this were `alerts: { type: Array, default: () => [alertFactory()] }`. I hope you see the problem here.

Comment: @EstusFlask * I hope you see the problem here* Yes I do. I took a hard stare at the typing that was a mess and appended to my answer what I think is the correct final version; Thanks a lot for all your help and perseverence!

Answer (score 0):

[`toRef`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#toref) returns a reference of type

```
interface Ref<T> {
  value: T
}
```

Calling `Object.values` on this returned the array of the type that you are getting.

To get the actual values of the object, you need to use  `toRef(...).values`.

Since `props.alert` is already reactive, `toRef` construct is unnecessary (as pointed by others too). So it would be better to use- `Object.values(props.alerts)`

Comment: `toRef(...).value` is nonsensical construct. `toRef(props, 'alerts').value` the same as `props.alerts`

Comment: @WoJ, your edit removed the explanation for the original problem. I have edited to include both the solutions.